# How to switch from Trial to Licenced CAL Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, rds, cals

I have finaly purchased my RDS CAL licences and now need to switch user from Trial to Licence but even if I remove from registry trial info from server or client the client still get Trial 120 days.

My server show 20 licences installed and avalable and 0 in use.

Comment: Last time I tried to activate RDP licenses for Windows Server 2008R2, the person on the phone said they couldn't process it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your correct type of CAL is installed.

If you install device CAL and your TS is set to issue User CAL, you will end up in the trial bucket.

**tsconfig.msc**, and validate in what mode your RDS server issue the CAL.